# How to fix UITableCells repeating in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, tableview

I know that there is already a few questions like this on here, but I can not get any of them to work.  Basically, I have a ui table view with a label and a switch in each cell.  Every 14 cells the switch will repeat. (The state of switch 1 will change switch 14, 28, etc...)

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell:

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyCell

    println(companies.count)
    cell.companyName.text = companies[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

A array of 31 company names gets loaded into the cells:

```
[Apple Inc, American Express Co, ... , Exxon Mobil Corp, Dow Jones]
```

The labels (names of the company) are on the left of the cell and the switches are on the right of the cell.

So how can I get the cells to stop reusing each other?

Comment: You need to set the state of the switch in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I suggest you add an answer with this so it can be accepted. I believe this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you have a model that represents this array of 31 company names. I'd personally be inclined towards an array of custom `Company` objects that consists of not only the name, but also the state of that company (i.e. is its switch on or off):

```
class Company {
    let name: String
    var state = false

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And, let's also assume that you've hooked up the `UISwitch` in the cell to an `IBOutlet` in the `CompanyCell` class:

```
class CompanyCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var companyName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var companySwitch: UISwitch!
}
```

If you then have a property, `companies` that is an array of these `Company` objects, then you could then implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return companies.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyCell

    let company = companies[indexPath.row]
    cell.companyName.text = company.name
    cell.companySwitch.on = company.state

    return cell
}
```

And you presumably want to hook up the "value changed" action for the switch in the cell to a method in the table view controller, too, which would update the model if the switch state changed:

```
@IBAction func didChangeValueInSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! CompanyCell
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    let company = companies[indexPath!.row]
    company.state = sender.on
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reuse a cell using this line

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyCell
```

an unused cell which is off the screen will be returned to you. This unused cell will have its properties - the state of your switch and the title of the company set according to its old value.

Now after that, you are updating the `companyName` to be set according to your data, which is perfect:

```
cell.companyName.text = companies[indexPath.row]
```

However, here you are not setting the state of your switch and it will still have the old value. You will need to maintain the data for your switch state and set it accordingly in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Something like this, where `switchStateArray` is the data source for your switch states:

```
cell.yourSwitch.on = switchStateArray[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 2):

in case of  UITableCells imageview repeating, use the function func `prepareForReuse()`

```
 class HomeFavoriteCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var imglLocation: UIImageView!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }
        override func prepareForReuse() {
            //set your cell's state to default here

            self.imglLocation.image = nil
        }
```

Comment: This clears image of 1st and repeated cell, is there any way to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are reusing the cell with

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyCell
```

To avoid this reset the switch in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// Configure the cell:

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyCell
  cell.mySwitch.on = false // or Whatever your switch name is (from CompanyCell class)
  cell.companyName.text = companies[indexPath.row]

return cell
}
```

or create new cell like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// Configure the cell:

  let cell = CompanyCell()
  cell.companyName.text = companies[indexPath.row]

return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't stop using `dequeue` just because you've got a switch. That's not a good idea. As rmaddy said, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should set the switch, just like it sets the `companyName`.

Comment: why am i getting down voted i'm just giving all the alternatives

Comment: You were down-voted because it is inadvisable to turn off dequeue logic as suggested by your original answer. The correct answer, which you've now incorporated here, is to keep dequeue logic, but just set the switch. I would suggest losing the "create new cell" discussion altogether, because that's simply a bad idea. Also, just setting the switch to `false` is a bad idea, too. You really should be referring to the model that indicates the state of that switch.

Comment: Could you guys help me with the cellForRowAtIndexPath function?  Sorry, I'm just learning swift.

Answer (score 0):

write `func prepareForReuse()` in your cell class

```
class CompanyCell : UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var companyName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var companySwitch: UISwitch!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
 // Initialization code
}
override func prepareForReuse() {
//set your cell's state to default here
self.companySwitch.isOn = false
}
}
```